# collapse row on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on this code but I have difficulties implementing properly. I wan to place the arrow in front of the question and synchronize the click event with the text.

jsfiddle.net/tx8paL7L/5/

Can you help me to fix the issue?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container faq_wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span10 offset1">
            <p>
                &nbsp;</p>
            <div class="faq-all-actions">
                <a class="faq-expand">Expand All</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="faq-collapse">Collapse All</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span10 offset1">
            <div class="question-wrapper">
                <div class="arrows">
                    &nbsp;</div>
                <div class="big-q">
                    Q</div>
                <div class="question">
                    <div class="arrow"></div><h6>Can I try the software before I buy it?</h6></div>
                <div class="answer-wrapper">
                    <div class="big-a">
                        A</div>
                    <div class="answer">
                        Yes! Simply <a href="/trial">download a free trial</a> and you&#39;ll have instant access to all features for 30 days, absolutely free. We don&#39;t require your credit card details or any commitment.</div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .answer-wrapper {
        display: none;
    }

    .arrow {
      margin: 1em;
    }

    .arrow::before {
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border: .5em solid transparent;
      border-left-color: gray;
      transform-origin: 0 50%;
      transition: transform .25s;
    }

    .arrow.down::before {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transition: transform .25s;
    }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document)
    .on('click','.row',function(){ 
        $(this).find('.answer-wrapper').slideToggle();
    })

    .on('click','.faq-expand',function(){
        $('.answer-wrapper').slideDown();
    })

    .on('click','.faq-collapse',function(){
        $('.answer-wrapper').slideUp();
    })

var arr = document.querySelector('.arrow');
arr.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle('down');
});
;
```

Comment: I'm confused, your slider seems to work but do you mean you want when the text is clicked the arrow to also move just as if you were clicking on the arrow?

Comment: Yes, correct. Please run the code snippet.

Comment: Yeah...I did. Your description isn't very helpful.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/tx8paL7L/12/ ?

Comment: Yes but the arrow should be before the text and the animation should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle with your javascript, the css still needs a bit of work:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tx8paL7L/21/)

Basically you were using the wrong selectors for your jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="container faq_wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span10 offset1">
            <p>
                &nbsp;</p>
            <div class="faq-all-actions">
                <a class="faq-expand">Expand All</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="faq-collapse">Collapse All</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span10 offset1">
            <div class="question-wrapper">
                <div class="arrows">
                    &nbsp;</div>
                <div class="big-q">
                    Q</div>
                <div class="question">
                    <div class="arrow"></div><h6>Can I try the software before I buy it?</h6></div>
                <div class="answer-wrapper">
                    <div class="big-a">
                        A</div>
                    <div class="answer">
                        Yes! Simply <a href="/trial">download a free trial</a> and you&#39;ll have instant access to all features for 30 days, absolutely free. We don&#39;t require your credit card details or any commitment.</div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    .on('click','.row .question-wrapper',function(){ 
        $(this).find('.answer-wrapper').slideToggle();
        $('.arrow').toggleClass('down');
    })

    .on('click','.faq-expand',function(){
        $('.answer-wrapper').slideDown();
        $('.arrow').addClass('down');
    })

    .on('click','.faq-collapse',function(){
        $('.answer-wrapper').slideUp();
        $('.arrow').removeClass('down');
    })

});
```

Comment: Yes! this is what I wanted. One small question the arrow and the text are not aligned? How this can be fixed?

Comment: I updated the Fiddle, by removing the margin on the arrow and decreasing the margin on the text. Please accept if this answered your question

Comment: One small detail can you update the arrow when it's expanded not to move to down like it's now. Just rotation without changing the place.

Comment: It's set to rotate 90 degrees, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

you've added `position:absolute` but done nothing to position the arrow .

add the following styles :

```
.arrow {
    position:relative; // you need to add position relative
    margin: 1em;
    padding-left:10px;
}

.arrow::before {
  position: absolute;
  left:100%; // define where you would like the arrow to be placed . 
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: .5em solid transparent;
  border-left-color: gray;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transition: transform .25s;
}
```

use position `relative` and `left` for perfectly positioning your arrow .

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tx8paL7L/15/)**

Answer (score 0):

To put arrow in front of the question you can use right 0 like this:

```
.arrow::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: .5em solid transparent;
  border-left-color: gray;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transition: transform .25s;
}
```

When you are layout an element on position absolute, you can "fix" the element relative to the parent if you want (top, bottom, right, left).

Comment: I updated the code but I don't see any improvement. Can you update the fiddle example please?

Comment: Please, try again, I saw arrow in the right position: http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=65msm1&s=8#.VWi6qecnjwc

Answer (score 0):

Add "left: 190px" to ".arrow::before"

```
.arrow::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: .5em solid transparent;
  border-left-color: gray;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transition: transform .25s;
    left: 190px;
}
```